# Removing blue border around Contact Button, using Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I've been implementing Bootstrap 3 onto my website, and I am currently experiencing this issue after having selecting the Contact button and closing the pop-up window that comes up:

[image: Contact Image Problem]

I do not want Contact to be lit up or highlighted in any manner after closing the popup. What do I need to edit in my CSS file to make this work?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is my code showing my nav-bar with all of my options. I believe I'm supposed to select something in here in order to edit the CSS of the Contact area. [image]

Comment: Add your code, don't simply add a picture, it doesn't really help anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
input[type="button"]:focus, 
input[type="submit"]:focus {    
    outline: none !important;   
 } /* for forms */ 

a:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
 } /* for anchor */
```

Comment: That got rid of the blue border problem, but "Contact" is still lit up after the element is selected.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, the `focus` pseudo class is used for styling an element that is currently targeted by the keyboard, or activated by the mouse.

By clicking on the button, Bootstrap adds styles to your button via `btn:focus`, `btn-primary:focus`, et cetera. One of the styles Bootstrap adds is a border around the button. In order to override this style, you can create a selector that hides the border of your button. For example, you could do something like this.

```
.btn:focus {
    border: none; 
}
```

If this doesn't work, try

```
 .btn:focus {
        border: none !important; 
 }
```

Comment: The problem here is that I'm not using a button per se, but Contact is on a navbar within an ul that has a bunch of classes.

See my edit for an image showing my code.

Comment: Using the DOM Explorer of your browser, select the element corresponding to your `Contact`. Click on contact and track the CSS changes the click made. You should notice that a border, or an outline was added to the element corresponding. Override that property in your CSS

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you see example: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/LLvkptuk/

Add this to your CSS:

```
.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  outline: none !important;
}
```